# Multi step form in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal

I am new in drupal.

How can i make the multistep form module work with the panels
or if there is any other module helps on the multistep forms

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

[Drupal 6 Multistep Form Domination Using Chaos Tools](http://nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6)

Comment: Beat me to it. Works every time. You could also use Webform with Pagebreak elements, but this implementation gives you far more flexibility.

Comment: @kevin: it absolutely does and it makes multi step so simple!!

Comment: @ayush  i download the module and enable it, and when i click the link it shows error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in /var/www/WC/drupal_website/sites/all/modules/wombat/wombat/wombat.module on line 26**

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still have this issue but I know you can now do multi step forms in webform module :D hope this helps anyone else asking the same thing!